# How to send localstorage data to email in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, javascript-objects, email-validation

I want to send client response to admin email account. So I want to use Javascript.

```
(e, t) => {
  const o = {
    msg: e,
    display_name: 'Customer Support',
    nick: 'agent:chatbot',
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    options: t ? ['paymentLink'] : void 0,
  };
  let messages = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('messages')) || []
  messages.push(o)
  window.localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(messages))
  messages = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('messages'))

  if (messages.length === 3) {

    window.localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify([]))
    document.getElementById("hidden-form").submit()
  }

  if (document.querySelector('#mes2').value || document.querySelector('#mes2').value.length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('#mes2').value = document.querySelector('#mes2').value + ',' + JSON.stringify(o)
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#mes2').value = JSON.stringify(o)

  }
  C([...j, o]);
},
```

Here is how I want to call the function, But I'm not sure what to put into the javascript function. From the research I've done I found that I can use EmailJs or mailto method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sendgrid, it's very simple.

[sendgrid.com](https://sendgrid.com/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing a code snippet of how you can send emails using sendgrid.